# how to change width of drop down menu responsive bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the responsive navbar from bootstrap. I want to change the width that changes to the drop down menu the default of this width is 768px but I want to change it with respect to my width. How should I do that I think I should do that with jquery using `$(windows).resize()` event.
Here is a sample of bootstrap navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Can't you just use width:30px;/*Your desired width*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two ways of doing this by using customization. Perhaps the fastest way to customize your bootstrap.css file is to use the Customizer at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.
At there you can change value for **@grid-float-breakpoint**. I tested with value 480px (original value was **@screen-sm**, which is same as 768px) After that click “Compile and Download” button at the end of the Customizer page. This will change the break point when the navbar collapses. At the bootstrap.css file for instance the following value is changed from

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
```

to this one below. The previous `@media` setting is from the default bootstrap.css download without customization.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
```

The second way of changing these settings is using LESS and compile the same value from source code. If you decide to make your own compilation, you can discover variable `@grid-float-breakpoint` at `variables.less` file at less directory of your bootstrap source installation (Bootstrap_dir/less/variables.less). More info at [Compiling CSS and JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt) and at [Bootstrap 3 Less Workflow Tutorial](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own class to the dropdown-menu and set width as you wish.

Comment: I want to use bootstarp navbar if I want to use my own class why should I ask question!!!!!!!

Comment: @Daniel.V Ok, try to do it like logan Sarav advises you below, but I advise you to use custom class to change width, because it's bad practice to override existing styles. And if you want to do something other just describe it more clearly and don't shout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu { width: yourwidth }
```